# Criar um objeto dinâmico de forma recursiva

Tags: javascript, recursão

Tô apanhando pra caramba pra fazer uma parada muito simples: montar um objeto em JavaScript por um array (string explodida).

Preciso montar um objeto de forma dinâmica (recursiva) assim:

```
{
  caneta: { cor: { hexadecimal: null } }
}
```

apenas com esse array: `['cor', 'caneta', 'hexadecimal']`

Preciso fazer isso de forma recursiva, pois meu array pode ter 1 propriedade, ou 800.

---

### Contexto

Tenho uma função que lê todos os formulários da minha página e monta, conforme o name de cada inputs, um objeto, e, conforme o id do formulário, armazena tudo dentro de um objeto pai (data).

#### Exemplo:

isso:

```
<form id="batata">
  <input name="tomate">
  <input name="banana" value="123">
</form>
```

gera um objeto assim:

```
batata: {
  tomate: null,
  banana: '123',
};
```

[Tentativa fracassada e contexto completo no Gist](https://gist.github.com/danielbonifacio/85351f88f560eae4ea6c1a29ddf59ee3)

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de querer algo recursivo. E a ordem/hierarquia das propriedades no objeto é diferente mesmo da ordem da array, como no seu exemplo?

Comment: Ela precisa chamar ela mesma para obter o mesmo tratamento em todos os casos, não? E sim, será do para frente.

Comment: Então no objeto é caneta/cor/hex e na array é cor/caneta/hex? É isso mesmo? Tem algum motivo pra não estar na mesma ordem? Critério?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, e se for para seguir a ordem das propriedades conforme consta na array (no seu exemplo tem uma inversão), não é necessário nada recursivo, basta um loop.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, com explicações linha por linha em forma de comentários:

```js
// Lista de propriedades, considerando que uma
// é filha da outra.
var arr = ['caneta', 'cor', 'hexadecimal'];

// Guarda temporariamente cada item da array
let prop;

// Estado inicial do objeto é vazio
let obj = {};

// Referencia adicional ao objeto.
// Será modificada dentro do loop.
let path = obj;

// Loop tratando os elementos da array,
// um a um, na ordem.
while (prop = arr.shift()) {
  // Cria a propriedade atual
  // (com valor null no último nível)
  path[prop] = arr.length ? {} : null;
  
  // Path agora será o valor da propriedade
  // que acabamos de inserir.
  path = path[prop];
}

// Imprime o resultado
console.log(obj);
```

**NOTA:** Esse código altera a array original, que fica vazia ao final do loop. Se não quiser esse efeito colateral, adapte para um `for(;;)` normal sem uso de `shift`, é simples.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborei uma alternativa utilizando funções do objeto `Array` do javascript que eu particularmente gosto bastante:

```js
var obj = ['cor', 'caneta', 'hexadecimal'] 
.concat([null]) //Remover caso não queira que o ultimo seja sempre null
.reverse()
.reduce(function(a,b){
 return {[b]:a}
});
console.log(obj)
```

Referencias:

> [Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - O método reduce() executa uma função reducer (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> [Array Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) - O método concat() retorna um novo array contendo todos os arrays ou valores passados como parâmetro
>
> [Array Reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) - O método reverse() inverte os itens de um array. O primeiro elemento do array se torna o último e o último torna-se o primeiro.

Comment: Boa ideia. Tenho somente dúvidas sobre suporte a esta sintaxe `{[b]:a}`, em engines JS mais antigos não deve funcionar.

Comment: Sim, neste caso basta criar um objeto vazio e adicionar o valor na posição: `var x = {}; x[b]= a; return x`